# Strange Animation Pixel Trails

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

We're currently developing an animated infographic at work and we're experiencing some slightly odd animation pixel trails when we include our code within our clients HTML template. Here's a link:

http://staging.catalysis.co.uk/polycom/infographic2/

It's only happening with the trains in the hero image and with the magnifying glass animation further down the page. Does any one know any reason why this would be happening and how it could be solved? It only seems to affect these animations and not others.

FYI we have to use JQuery 1.7 and the animations need to be supported in IE9+ (IE8 support is also required though we are utilising still PNGs for this)

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Added image for clarity
[image]

Comment: Not seeing any pixel trails, FF 33.0 Beta 5 (or 6).

Comment: I don't see any in FF either, but have observed them intermittently on both Safari & Chrome, maybe something to do with Webkit based browsers?

Comment: verify those trails, latest chrome on mavericks

Comment: google search `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0)` - applied to an element containing animated elements, you can sometimes clear artifacts because it enables hardware acceleration. I've noticed it sometimes makes things worse, but don't give up if it does that for you. I just separated the animated elements into different parent containers and messed with z-indexing to resolve display orders.

Comment: Even if the element is animated using JQuery and "animate()"?